# String como nombre de atributo

Tags: python-3.x, poo, mongodb

Tengo una instancia del cliente de mi base de datos y me gustaría pasar una instancia de la base de datos y la colección que quiero usar como String al cliente. ¿Saben como puedo utilizar String como nombre de atributo?

```
db_url = "mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@cluster0.n2hnd.mongodb.net/a_company?retryWrites=true" \
                      "&w=majority"
```

Aquí esta la función que me gustaría crear:

```
def save_in_mongo(self, url, db, collection, perfume):
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(url)
    db = client.db
    fragrance = db.collection
```

Pero no sé como utilizar los argumentos de la función como atributos del cliente de *MongoDB*.

Comment: La instancia del cliente se crea usando la cadena `url`. Puedes construir dicha cadena de forma dinámica, sustituyendo el nombre de la base de datos. En cuanto a la colección, puedes usar la sintaxis de corchete: `fragance = db[collection_name]`. En cuanto pueda te preparo una respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como afirmo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/411522/string-como-nombre-de-atributo#comment735760_411522), y según lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, puedes usar los valores necesarios pasando como argumento los mismos como cadenas.

En tu método se ve que deseas recibir la `url`, la base de datos, la colección e imagino que el documento a ser insertado (*perfume*).

**SOLUCION**

Partiendo de esto, supongamos que la función recibe los siguientes valores:

- `url`: Cadena de conexión a Mongo Atlas: `"mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@cluster0.n2hnd.mongodb.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority"`
- `db`: Cadena con el nombre de la base de datos: `"a_company"`
- `col`: Cadena con el nombre de la colección: `"fragance"`
- `doc`: Documento a ser insertado en la base de datos.

Nótese que la cadena de conexión no incluye el nombre de la base datos.

Teniendo esto, podríamos hacer la función para que dados estos parámetros inserte el documento en la colección:

```py
def save_in_mongo(self, url, db, col, doc):
    client = MongoClient(url)
    database = client[db]
    collection = database[col]
    # operaciones con el documento
    # por ejemplo insertar el documento
    doc_id = collection.insert_one(doc).inserted_id
    return doc_id
```

Definiendo la función de esta manera, podemos pasar los parámetros de la siguiente forma, por ejemplo:

```py
db_url = "mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@cluster0.n2hnd.mongodb.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
db_name = "a_company"
col_name = "fragance"
perfume = {
  "name": "Mi perfume pythónico",
  "price": 65
}

perfume_id = mi_instancia.save_in_mongo(db_url, db_name, col_name, perfume)
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.